# Nested While Loops in C

Tags: c, loops

I am having issues making this nested while loop to work in this terminal application.I am trying to build a system with Clients and an Admin with certain
capabilities for each.

```
scanf("%s",sign_in_choice);
int admin_result, client_result, number_of_clients, x, c;
admin_result = strcmp(sign_in_choice,"Admin");
client_result = strcmp(sign_in_choice,"Client");
char client_choice[10];
int client_username;
int client_password;
int client_choice_log_in, client_choice_register;


while(x == 0)
{

    if(admin_result == 0 )

    {

    printf("Welcome to Admin Page\n");

    }

    else if(client_result == 0)

    {   
        printf("Testing");
        while(c == 0)
        {
        //START OF CLIENT PAGE
        printf("Welcome to Client Page\n");
        printf("Register or Log in?\n");
        scanf("%s",client_choice);
        client_choice_log_in = strcmp(client_choice,"Login");
        client_choice_register = strcmp(client_choice,"Register");
            if(client_choice_register == 0)
            {
            // REGISTER
            reg(client_number);
            // END OF REGISTER
            }
            else if(client_choice_log_in == 0)
            {
        //LOG IN
            printf("Please enter your credentials\n");
            printf("Enter your afm:\n");
            scanf("%d", &client_username);
            printf("Enter your year of birth:\n");
            scanf("%d", &client_password);
            login(client_username, client_password, client_number, client_verify);
        //END OF LOG IN
            // PERSONAL CLIENT PAGE
                i = client_number;
                printf("Welcome to your Personal Client Page: %s \n", client_array[i].client_name);
                printf("Verify : %d\n",client_verify);
            // END OF PERSONAL CLIENT PAGE
            }
            else
            {
            printf("Invalid input.Please try again.\n");
            scanf("%s",client_choice);
            client_choice_log_in = strcmp(sign_in_choice,"Login");
            client_choice_register = strcmp(sign_in_choice,"Register");
            }
        // END OF CLIENT PAGE
        }
    }
    else
    {
    printf("Invalid input.Please try again.\n");
    scanf("%s",sign_in_choice);
    admin_result = strcmp(sign_in_choice,"Admin");
    client_result = strcmp(sign_in_choice,"Client");
    }
}
```

If I remove the while( c == 0) loop the code works.It allows me to select either Login or Register and continue.If I leave the loop as is when I input 'Client' the program goes into an infinite loop printing 'testing'.In addition if I enter 'Admin' the program again goes into infinite loop printing 'welcome to admin page' although the while loop appears later in the program.At least in my understanding the while(c == 0) loop should only affect what is contained within it not outside it,at least in this particular case.I am using Devc 5.11.Also I tried compiling and running through vs code and codeblocks and in those cases the program doesn't even go beyond the 'Admin Client' choice in the beginning.As you can see I have some functions and and structs not shown here but they should not affect my problem since everything works fine until I try to make this nested while loop work.

Comment: It is highly unreadable

Comment: Please edit your post and remove irrelevant codes to the problem, and show a clear example of the problem

Comment: It's very hard to read without any kind of spacing between sections of the code, but it seem you're using some variables while they are uninitialized. That means their value will be *indeterminate* (and seem random).

Comment: I removed some code which wasn't needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`c` is uninitialized, so it has an undefined behavior, which depends on your compiler. You will need to initialize your variables. And to make sure you do not have infinite loops, you must handle the case when you have a client and `c` is not 0. You can set it to 0, or something, just don't leave there an `else` which will always be entered, will not change `c` and will have a loop inside it, which depends on the value of `c`.

Maybe I missed it, but I do not see how you set the value of `c` inside the `while (c == 0)` loop, so if `c` happens to be 0, that inner loop seems to be infinite as well.

Comment: I initialized the values and ti seems to work better now.I thought the values default to 0.

Comment: @spyrosgr uninitialized variables have undefined behavior in C, this is an important lesson for the future. If my answer solved your problem, you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.